# Using python (via requests or otherwise) to retrieve an html table selected by drop down

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I'm trying to pull historical weather data from the following site: https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/usa/boston/historic

There are two dropdown menus that I need to select in order to load the table for any particular day: one for the month/year and the other for the day.

I've been attempting to get the data using requests in the following manner:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import pandas as pd

website = "https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/usa/boston/historic"
payload = {"month": '2018-06',"wt-his-select":"20180608"}
page_response = requests.get(website, data = payload, timeout=5).text
sp = soup(page_response,'lxml')
My_table = sp.find('table',id='wt-his')
table_rows = My_table.find_all('tr')
rows = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all(['th','td'])
    rows.append([i.text for i in td])
pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

However running this code, I only get the values for today instead for for 2018/06/08- what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT:  if you can't do this with requests, then how do you do it?

Comment: _There are two dropdown menus that I need to select in order to load the table for any particular day: one for the month/year and the other for the day._ Then you probably won't be able to use Requests for this, unless all the data is already on the page and the dropdown only shows/hides it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data of this page load through `JSON` dynamically. You can find this `AJAX` request in network tab when you change date. But the problem with `JSON` is that it is not into the proper format so when you use `response.json()` it gives you an error. So you have to convert your data into proper format.

```
import re
import requests

url = 'https://www.timeanddate.com/scripts/cityajax.php?n=usa/boston&mode=historic&hd=20180608&month=6&year=2018&json=1'

headers = {
'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36',
}
response  = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

raw_json = eval(response.text.replace(',{c:', '""",{c:').replace('{c:', '"""{c:')[::-1].replace(']', ']"""', 1)[::-1])
for i in raw_json:
    json_data = eval(i.replace('{c:', '{"c":').replace('{h:', '{"h":').replace('{s:', '{"s":').replace(',h:', ',"h":').replace('="', '=\'').replace('">', '\'>').replace('" ', '\' '))

    visibility = json_data['c'][8]['h'].replace('&nbsp;', '')
    barometer = json_data['c'][7]['h']
    humidity = json_data['c'][6]['h']
    wind = json_data['c'][4]['h'].replace('\/', '/')
    weather = json_data['c'][3]['h']
    temp = json_data['c'][2]['h'].replace('&nbsp;', '')
    time = re.findall(r'\d{2}:\d{2}', json_data['c'][0]['h'])[0]

    print(time, temp, weather, wind, humidity, barometer, visibility, end='    |   ')
```

OUTPUT:

```
00:54 14°C Overcast. 15 km/h 78% 1020 mbar 16km    |   01:54 14°C Overcast. 13 km/h 78% 1020 mbar 16km    |   02:54 13°C Passing clouds. 15 km/h 84% 1020 mbar 16km    |   03:54 13°C Passing clouds. 15 km/h 84% 1020 mbar 16km    |   04:54 13°C Clear. 15 km/h 87% 1020 mbar 16km    |   05:54 13°C Passing clouds. 20 km/h 90% 1020 mbar 16km    |   06:54 14°C Passing clouds. 13 km/h 81% 1020 mbar 16km    |   07:54 17°C Passing clouds. 11 km/h 73% 1020 mbar 16km    |   08:54 19°C Passing clouds. 7 km/h 66% 1020 mbar 16km    |   09:54 21°C Scattered clouds. 13 km/h 66% 1020 mbar 16km    |   10:54 24°C Passing clouds. 7 km/h 48% 1020 mbar 16km    |   11:54 25°C Passing clouds. 13 km/h 47% 1019 mbar 16km    |   12:54 26°C Broken clouds. 7 km/h 42% 1019 mbar 16km    |   13:54 27°C Partly sunny. 9 km/h 42% 1018 mbar 16km    |   15:54 21°C Partly sunny. 13 km/h 70% 1018 mbar 16km    |   16:54 22°C Broken clouds. 15 km/h 63% 1018 mbar 16km    |   17:54 21°C Scattered clouds. 11 km/h 64% 1017 mbar 16km    |   18:54 21°C Scattered clouds. 9 km/h 64% 1018 mbar 16km    |   19:54 22°C Scattered clouds. 11 km/h 57% 1018 mbar 16km    |   20:54 22°C Passing clouds. 6 km/h 59% 1018 mbar 16km    |   21:54 21°C Passing clouds. No wind 66% 1019 mbar 16km    |   22:54 22°C Passing clouds. 6 km/h 57% 1019 mbar 16km    |   23:54 21°C Clear. 6 km/h 59% 1018 mbar 16km
```

Comment: Your rock!  Thanks so much.